# Computing homotopy classes of maps between small finite CW complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, higher-homotopy-groups

Given finite CW complexes $X$ and $Y$ with $X$ connected, how can one go about computing the set of (baseless) homotopy classes of maps $[X, Y]$? Does a general procedure/algorithm exist?

I should say that I am primarily interested in the case where the space $X$ (and possibly also $Y$) has a low dimension, say $\mathrm{dim}(X)\leq 3$. Of course the problem is extremely hard in general.

I apologise if this is a stupid question, my background is in physics and I am not aware of any good references on this matter - if there are any then I would gratefully read them!

Comment: All spheres are finite CW complexes. If there is a general algorithmic procedure to compute homotopy classes of maps between finite CW-complexes, we will be able to compute the homotopy groups of spheres...

Comment: Of course. What about for low dimensions?

Comment: It's not a full answer to your question, but have you looked at minimal models? Under some nontrivial but common conditions on $X$ (simply-connectedness, for example), they allow the computation of $\pi_* X\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ from the ring structure of $H^*(X)$, and the latter can be computed from the CW-complex structure of $X$.

Comment: It's also not exactly what you're looking for, but take a look at the mapping class group of a surface.